# sorting a file without using temporary files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sorting

I want to sort a file in unix shell. Can I redirect my result into my input file?

e.g. if my input file is foo then can I use

```
    sort foo > foo
```

or I should use:

```
    sort -o foo foo
```

What would be difference between above two?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
sort -o foo foo
```

From the `man` page:

> `-o OUTPUT-FILE'
>        Write output to OUTPUT-FILE instead of standard output.  If
>        OUTPUT-FILE is one of the input files,`sort' copies it to a
>        temporary file before sorting and writing the output to
>        OUTPUT-FILE.

`sort foo > foo` means writing output to the standard output which is redirected to the output file. Before redirecting, `>` will truncate/overwrite the output file if one is exist. Since both the input and output files are same, you will lose the input file information.